# Is it possible to insertMany into MongoDB without using promise?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is something like this possible?

```
db.collection.insertMany(records);
```

I currently have it as:

```
await db.collection.insertMany(records);
```

And this way with `await` works.. but if I get rid of it, it seems to not do anything. I have many records to insert, and I don't want to wait over an hour (and I don't want to pay for the non-free tier, as this is a hobby project). Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you basically just want to send it off into space and now wait for any callback?

Comment: It should still do exactly the same even if you don't await the result. But of course, you won't be able to see the results while it is still in-flight, and you don't want to shut down your application before it is done.

Comment: @Thilo Nope, I keep checking mongoDB and it's not inserting the documents

Comment: @mwilson Basically. It's a script that inserts test data into my collection. I need like 10 million records, but it doesn't seem to insert anything without the `await`

Comment: Well, `db.collection.insertMany(records);` is a promise and therefore you should be able to do `db.collection.insertMany(records).then(  _callback => return );` I think that should do exactly what you want. I have not tested it though. My theory is that killing your application before the callback completes is going to cancel any in-process requests. Maybe there's a better way to do it?

Comment: `insertMany` will wait until _all_ of the documents have been inserted before the promise completes. If you want to speed it up, I'd either try batching your inserts into smaller groups (10 million records is a decent number to handle all at once), or using `mongoimport` (which is designed to import records quickly).

Comment: Using `mongoimport` does seem like a very good idea to handle bulk imports